# SecureSocial on Play 1.2.x behind Apache

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x, securesocial

I run SecureSocial on a Play 1.2.x installation (on port :9000). Access to the application is via Apache httpd running on port :80, which will then forward the requests.

As for SecureSocial, the URL in the request is now localhost:9000 (see `securesocial.provider.OAuth2Provider.doAuth(Map<String, Object>):111`), the authentification call will fail.

I look for a clever solution to this problem which doesn't involve

- Running Play not in front of httpd
- Hacking SecureSocial

Comment: Did you set the `application.baseUrl` in your `application.conf`? For the "production" environment, for example, this would be `%production.application.baseUrl=http://yourdomain.tld/`

Comment: According to `play.mvc.Router.getBaseUrl()`, this parameter is only used when there is no Request at the moment -- which is the case here, and then, the domain gets pulled out of the Request without looking into `application.baseUrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion on the [Play Mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/pyRGcEypuYg) using the solution provided in the [Play Bugtracker](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1406-play-123-124-playmvcrouter-does-not-fully-support-proxied-ssl):

Set, in `application.conf`, the parameter `XForwardedSupport` to `all`, or a list of allowed proxies.